# When does $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+...}}}=0$?

Tags: roots, radicals, nested-radicals

Consider the function $f$ defined as the limit of the functions
$$f_0(x)=\sqrt{x}$$
$$f_1(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+1}}$$
$$f_2(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2}}}$$
$$...$$
so that $f(x)$ is defined iff $f_n(x)$ is defined for some $n$. The unique root $x_0$ of the function $f$ satisfies $f(x_0)=0$, and it can be alternatively expressed as the limit of the roots of $f_0, f_1, f_2, ...$. See the graphs below:

[image: Graphs]

Can anyone find an expression equal to this limit? I realize that the chances of something nice and closed-form are slim - can we find a series, integral, or even nested radical representation of the real root of $f(x)$?

Comment: Isn't $f_n(x) \geq \sqrt x $ for all $n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, but not for *negative* values of $x$, for which $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined.

Comment: Numeric calculation gives me a root of approximately $$x \approx -1.2110372835124715149669698\ldots.$$

Comment: @heropup. Could you show me how you made it ? If you used Mathematica, could you show me the syntax ? Tanks in advance.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My response was too long for a comment so I made it an answer.

Comment: The numerical result doesn't have a match in the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html), so it's at least not a simple expression in well-known constants.

Comment: I think one issue that might make the problem harder is that you can't use continuity. Isn't $f(x)$ discontinuous at its root?

Comment: @MaximGilula No, I believe it is continuous. Differentiable, however, it is not.

Comment: Why would this function be continuous at its root, but $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}$ not? That would be very surprising to me.

Answer (score 12):

To address how I performed the computation, this was done in *Mathematica* using the following code:

```
F[x_, n_] := Fold[Sqrt[x + #1 + #2] &, 0, Reverse[Range[n + 1] - 1]]
FindRoot[F[x, 500] == 0, {x, -1.2}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

The first command defines $f_n(x)$; the second chooses $n = 500$, which due to the extremely rapid convergence of $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1}$, is more than sufficient to converge to the desired precision with a short computation time.  You can check that the result is accurate by choosing $n = 100$ and seeing that the result is unchanged to $50$ digits of precision; indeed, even to $100$ digits of precision.  I would put an upper bound on the error to be less than $10^{-n}$ when using $f_n$ instead of $f$.

Comment: Thank you ! Very instructive to me. Cheers and $\to +1$

Answer (score 4):

Not really a solution, but here's a different different perspective that was too long for a comment:

We have
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{x+f(x+1)}
$$
or equivalently
$$
f(x)^2 =x+f(x+1)
$$
which gives us a pseudo-recursion for $f'(x)$:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1+f'(x+1)}{2f(x)}
$$
Just formally, we get:\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2f(x)} + \frac1{4f(x)f(x+1)} +\frac1{8f(x)f(x+1)f(x+2)}+\cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{n+1}}\prod_{k=0}^n\frac1{f(x+k)}
\end{eqnarray}
Does this series converge? It seems certain that it ought to, and indeed since $f(x)\ge\sqrt{x}$, one gets the upper bound for each summand is $$
\frac1{2^{n+1}}\prod_{k=0}^n\frac1{\sqrt{x+k}}
$$
which is clearly summable (and hence we also have uniform convergence on closed intervals when $x>0$, validating that this is indeed the derivative of $f$, not simply formally).

Furthermore, for the $m$th derivative when $m>1$, we have $$
\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j} f^{(j)}(x)f^{(m-j)}(x) = f^{(m)}(x+1)
$$
which can be solved for $f^{(m)}$ by taking $$
f^{(m)}(x) =\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j} f^{(j)}(x) f^{(m-j)}(x) + f^{(m)}(x+1)}{2f(x)}
$$
and similarly gives us (at least formally!)$$
f^{(m)}(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j} f^{(j)}(x+n) f^{(m-j)}(x+n)}{2^{n+1}\prod_{k=0}^n f(x+n)}
$$
One should similarly be able to show uniform convergence of these series.

Now, observe that the formula $$
f(x+1) = f(x)^2 - x
$$
allows us to *explicitly* compute $f(x+n)$ in terms of $f(x)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Say $f(x+n) = g_n(f(x),x)$. Then $f(x+n) = f(x+n-1)^2 - x-n = g_{n-1}(f(x),x)^2 - x - n$, so we have the following explicit recursion for $g_n$:$$
g_n(y,x) = \begin{cases}y & n=0\\ g_{n-1}(y)^2 - x - n & n>0 \end{cases}
$$
Thus our derivative formula actually becomes a differential equation:$$
f'(x) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{n+1}}\prod_{k=0}^n\frac1{g_k(f(x),x)}
$$
This is not extremely helpful, but it is mildly interesting! It will also imply that $f$ is the *unique* differentiable function satisfying $f(x)^2 = x+f(x+1)$ with its initial value $f(0)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$.

---

**Update:** A sort-of solution. The root is $$
r = - \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 + \cdots} - \sqrt{ 1 + \cdots}} - \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \cdots} - \sqrt{1+\cdots}}} - \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3 + \cdots} - \sqrt{1 + \cdots}} - \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \cdots} - \sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}
$$
In case it's not clear what the pattern is, any time you see $n+\cdots$ read it recursively as $$n+\cdots=n+\sqrt{n+1 + \cdots} - \sqrt{1+\cdots}$$

To see how this is a solution, one can see from this recursive reading:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{1+r + \sqrt{2+r + \cdots}} = \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{1 + \cdots} + \sqrt{2 +\cdots}} = -r
\end{eqnarray}
and hence $$
f(r) = \sqrt{r + \sqrt{1+r + \sqrt{2+r+\cdots}}} = \sqrt{r - r} = 0
$$
A recursive way to find this root is to observe, using $f(x)^2 = x + f(x+1)$, one has $f(r+1) + r = 0$ or equivalently, $r+1 = 1-f(r+1)$. Thus $r+1$ is the unique fixed point of $x\to 1 - f(x)$. Hence you have formally$$
r+1 = 1-f(1-f(1-\cdots))
$$
In fact the fixed point is attracting; one can show inductively that $f_n'(1) < 1$ for all $n$, and hence $f'(1)<1$. Using the fact that $r<-1$ and that $f'$ is decreasing, one has $$
f'(r+1) = \frac{1+f'(r+2)}{2f(r+1)} = \frac{1+f'(r+2)}{-2r} \le \frac{1+f'(1)}{-2r} < \frac{1}{-r} < 1
$$
Thus the derivative of $1-f(x)$ at $x=r+1$ is less than $1$ in absolute value, so iterating it does converge to its fixed point. Defining a sequence $c_n$ recursively by $$
c_{n} = 1 - f_n(c_{n-1})
$$
with $c_0 = 1$, one obtains a sequence that converges to $r+1$. The first few terms:\begin{eqnarray}
c_0 &=& 1\\
c_1 &=& 0 \\
c_2 &=& 1-\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt2}\\
c_3 &=& 1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt2}+\sqrt{3-\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt2}+\sqrt{4-\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt2}}}}}
\end{eqnarray}
clearly this gets unwieldy pretty fast. I programed this recursion into Haskell and it seems to converge pretty fast. After $c_{65}$ on my computer shows the values oscillating between $-0.21103728351247164$ and $-0.21103728351247142$, so I guess the root is $$
r\approx  -1.211037283512471\dots
$$
which agrees with the numerical calculations from other users.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is equivalent to proving that there exists some real number $r$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(r) = 0 
\end{equation}
where $f_n = g_n^0(x)$ and $g^k_n$ is defined by the recurrence 
\begin{equation}
g_n^k(x) = 
\begin{cases} \sqrt {x+k} & \text{if }n=1 \\ 
\sqrt{x + k +  g^{k+1}_{n-1}(x)}  & \text{o.w.} \\ 
\end{cases}. 
\end{equation}
Therefore, by definition, we have 
\begin{equation}
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} \sqrt {x} & \text{if }n=1 \\ 
\sqrt{x +  g^{1}_{n-1}(x)}  & \text{o.w.} \\ 
\end{cases},
\end{equation}
which after proving the following:
\begin{equation}
 g_n^1(x)  = g_n^0(x+1) ,
\end{equation} 
 by a simple induction, gives us that
\begin{equation}
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} \sqrt {x} & \text{if }n=1 \\ 
\sqrt{x +  f_{n-1}(x+1)}  & \text{o.w.} \\ 
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}

Let us suppose that $r_n - f_{n-1}(r_n+1) =  \epsilon_n$ and that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \epsilon_n  = 0 $ then we have that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(r_n) = 0.
\end{equation}

One possible route to find this is to consider the growth of the sequence
\begin{equation}
\delta_n(x)  =  f_n(x+1) - f_n(x). 
\end{equation}

Therefore given a good approximation to $r_n$, an educated guess for $r_{n+1} $ should be some
\begin{equation}
r_{n+1} \in [r_{n} - 1, r_{n}],
\end{equation}
this is because
\begin{equation}
f_{n+1}^2(r_{n} - \epsilon) = r_{n} - \epsilon + f_n(r_{n} - \epsilon) +\delta_n(r_{n} - \epsilon)  
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\delta_n(r_{n} - \epsilon) =   f_n(r_{n} +1- \epsilon) - f_n(r_{n} - \epsilon) =  f_n(r_{n} +(1-\epsilon)) - f_n(r_{n} - \epsilon)
\end{equation}
gives us that we should be looking for some 
\begin{equation}
-\delta_n(r_{n} - \epsilon)  \approx r_{n} - \epsilon + f_n(r_{n} - \epsilon)
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to saying 
\begin{equation}
-\delta_n(r_{n} - \epsilon)  - f_n(r_{n} - \epsilon) \approx r_{n} - \epsilon 
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
-f_n(r_{n} + (1- \epsilon))  \approx r_{n} - \epsilon, 
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
f_n(r_{n} + (1- \epsilon))  \approx \epsilon - r_n .
\end{equation}

which is a ***"sort-of" fixed point equation***. Now we are getting somewhere!

We now have a method to recursively approximate solutions from previous solutions; *i.e.* 
 \begin{equation}
f_n(r_{n} + (1- \epsilon)) =   \epsilon -r_{n}  \implies f_{n+1}(r_{n} - \epsilon) = 0  . 
\end{equation}

Let us compute $r_n$ for small values to verify the solution.

1. $f_1(x) = \sqrt x $ is the base case and it has the obvious solution $r_1 = 0$.
2. Since $f_1(0) = 0$ and $\sqrt{1- \frac{\sqrt5  -1}{2}} = \frac{\sqrt5  -1}{2} $ we have an exact solution in the form of $r_1 = 0 $, $\epsilon = \frac{\sqrt5  -1}{2} $, and $r_2 = r_1 - \epsilon $; i.e. $f_2 (r_1 - \epsilon) = f_2\left(\frac{ 1-\sqrt5 }{2}\right) = 0$.
3. Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} (3 - \sqrt{5})$ then one can easily check that both $f_2(r_2 +1 - \epsilon) = \epsilon - r_2 $ and $f_3(r_2  - \epsilon) =f_3(-1) = 0 . $
4. Let $\epsilon = 0.153761 $ then one can easily check that both $f_2(r_3 + 1 - \epsilon) \approx \epsilon - r_3 $ and $f_4(r_3  - \epsilon) = f_3(-1.153761) \approx 0 . $

***In conclusion, we have the following recursion relation for the roots***

> \begin{equation}
> r_{n+1} = 
> \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }n=1 \\ 
>  r_n - \epsilon  & \text{if } f_n(r_n +1 - \epsilon) =  r_n - \epsilon  \\ 
> \end{cases};
> \end{equation}

however, it is possible that a recursive analysis of the following two functions

1. $f'_n(x)$
2. $\delta_n(x)$

could give a better recursive bound $b_n  < b_{n-1}<1 $ on the intervals

\begin{equation}
r_{n+1} \in [r_n-b, r_n]
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The task standing.}}$

Let $-r$ is the root of $f(x).$

Since $f(x)$ is increasing function and 
$$f(-r)=0,\quad f(-1) > f_2(-1) = 0,$$ 
then $r>1.$

At the same time,
\begin{cases}
f(x+1) = f^2(x)-x\\
f(-r)=0\\
f(-r+1) = r\\
f(-r+2) = r^2+r-1\\
f(-r+3)= (r^2+r-1)^2 + r-2 = (r-1)(r^4+3r^2+2r+1)\dots.\tag1
\end{cases}

Besides,
\begin{cases}
f'(x+1) = 2f(x)f'(x)-1\\
f'(-r) = \infty\\
f'(-r+2) = 2rf'(-r+1)-1\\
f'(-r+3) = 2(r^2-r+1)f'(-r+2)-1\dots\tag2
\end{cases}

Conditions $(1),(2)$ allow to define unknown parameters in the various parametric representations of $f(x).$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Inverse polynomial model.}}$

Let the inverse function is $f^{-1}(x)=g(y),$ then 
\begin{cases}
g(0) = -r\\
g'(0)=0\\
g(r) = -r+1\\
g(r^2+r-1) = -r+2\\
g((r-1)(r^4+3r^2+2r+1)) = -r+3,\tag3
\end{cases}
and the coefficients of the cubic approximating polynomial in the form of
$$g(y)=-r+qy^2+py^3\tag4$$
can be obtained from the algebraic system
\begin{cases}
-r+1 = -r + pr^2 + qr^3\\
-r+2 = -r + p(r^2+r-1)^2 + q(r^2+r-1)^3\\
-r+3 = -r + p(r-1)^2(r^4+3r^2+2r+1)^2 + q(r-1)^3(r^4+3r^2+2r+1)^3,
\end{cases}
with the single positive solution
$$p\approx 0.0622998,\quad q\approx 0.606587,\quad r\approx1.21088$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7B-1%2Bq%20r%5E2%20%2Bp%20r%5E3%2C%20-2%2B%20q%20%28r%5E2%2Br-1%29%5E2%2Bp%20%28r%5E2%2Br-1%29%5E3%2C%20-3%2B%28r-1%29%5E2%28r%5E3%2B3r%5E2%2B2r%2B1%29%5E2%28q%2Bp%20%28r-1%29%28r%5E3%2B3r%5E2%2B2r%2B1%29%29%7D%29%3D%7B0.%2C0.%2C0.%7D)).

Therefore, the cubic model estimation of root of $f(x)$ is $\color{brown}{\mathbf{-1.21088}}.$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Power model.}}$

Taking in account conditions $(1),$ can be used the explicit power model
$$f(x) = r(x+r)^p,\tag5$$

where
\begin{cases}
r^2+r-1 = r\cdot 2^p\\
(r-1)(r^3+3r^2+2r+1) = r\cdot 3^p,
\end{cases}

[image: Power model parameters]

The power model estimation of root of $f(x)$ is $\color{brown}{\mathbf{-1.21168}}.$

Plot of the inverse functions for the considered models see below.

[image: Inverse functions]

Using of detalized models can improve approximations accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but it may be fruitful to consider a sequence of functions $g_n(x)$ where $g_0(x) = x$ and

$$g_n(x) = [g_{n-1}(x)]^2 - x - n$$

In particular,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x_0) = 0.$$

I found this by setting

$$f_n(x) = 0$$

and moving all roots to the other side. For example, with $n = 2$,

$$\begin{align*}
0 &= \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + 1 + \sqrt{x + 2 + \sqrt{x+3}}}}, \\
-x &= \sqrt{x + 1 + \sqrt{x + 2 + \sqrt{x+3}}}, \\
x^2 - x - 1 &= \sqrt{x+2 + \sqrt{x+3}}, \\
(x^2 - x - 1)^2 - x - 2 &= \sqrt{x+3}, \\
((x^2 - x - 1)^2 - x - 2)^2 - x - 3 &= 0.
\end{align*}$$

This makes it clear that if $a$ satisfies $f_n(a) = 0$, then $g_n(a) = 0$. I suppose then that the solution to the question is dependent on if the sequence $g_n$ defined by $g_0 = x$ and

$$g_n = g_{n-1}^2 - x - n$$

has an explicit form.

Comment: I tried solving $g_n(x)=0$.  $g_n(x)$ is a degree $2^n$ polynomial and for larger values of $n$, the equation $g_n(x)=0$ has an enormous number of real roots all very close to the correct root.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is apparently no representation of the root of $f(x)$ as a series, integral, or nested radical, this answer will explain how to find the root by numerically solving $f(x)=0.$  Of course, if you have Mathematica, you could use the Mathematica code in heropup's answer.  But the Mathematica code doesn't explain exactly how the root is computed.  Since the derivative of $f(x)$ is infinite at the root $x=r$ and $f$ is undefined for $x\lt r,$ neither Newton's method nor the secant method work.  But the bisection method will work if you make a slight change in the definition of $f(x)$: if any argument of a square root during the computation of $f(c)$ is negative, define the value of $f(c)$ as negative one.

The function $f(x)$ can be generalized by replacing the sequence $1, 2, 3, \dots$ with the more general arithmetic sequence $C, 2C, 3C, \dots$ (where $C$ is some non-negative real number).  The following C code computes the root of $f_N(x,C)$ in quad precision arithmetic.  It computes the roots of $f_{50}(x,1)$, $f_{50}(x,2)$, and $f_{50}(x,3)$ as $-1.21103728351247151496696981615$, $-1.62419058855232395793631994913$, and $-1.94153569702169327219376232801$.

```
// Compute f(x,N,C).  
//
// f(x,0,C) = sqrt(x),
// f(x,1,C) = sqrt(x + sqrt(x+C)),
// f(x,2,C) = sqrt(x + sqrt(x+C + sqrt(x+2C))), ...
//
// Return -1 if any argument of sqrt is negative.
//
__float128 f(__float128 x, int N, __float128 C)
{
  __float128 fval=0;
  for (int i=0; i<=N; i++) {
    fval = x + C*(N-i) + fval;
    if (fval < 0) return -1;
    fval = sqrtq(fval);
  }

  return fval;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char f128_s[256];

  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Usage: (N) (C)\n");
    return 1;
  }
  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  __float128 C = strtoflt128(argv[2], NULL);
  if (N < 2) {
    printf("N must be at least 2\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Solve f(x,N,C) = 0 for x using bisection method.  Exit bisection
  // method loop when maximum number of iterations is exceeded or
  // length of interval containing root is smaller than specified
  // tolerance.
  __float128 x0=-100, x1=0;
  int maxit=150, numit=1; 
  __float128 min_interval_len=2e-32, root;
  while ( 1 ) {
    if (numit >= maxit) break;

    root = (x0 + x1)*0.5;
    if (x1-x0 < min_interval_len) break;

    __float128 fval = f(root,N,C);

    if (fval > 0) x1 = root;
    else x0 = root;

    numit++;
  }

  quadmath_snprintf(f128_s, 256, "%.30Qg", root);
  printf("root=%s, numit=%d\n", f128_s, numit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is a quick experiment in `pari/gp` (known for rapid run and high precision computations) using a precision of 1000 decimals, to locate the zero point of (the square of) the function defined in the OP:

```
? \p 1000
? N = 10000.;
? { f(x) = a = x+N+1; for(k=0, N, a = x + N - k + sqrt(a)); a; }
? solve( x=-2, -1, f(x) )
%15 = -1.21103728351247151496696981615341479894622010332776604004744966664016950841178...
```

and the next (nine hundred or so) decimals were omitted.

Let us take a look now from the mathematical point of view.

---

Let $h_n:(-2,\infty)$ be the function
$$
h_n(x)=x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{\dots +\sqrt{x+n}}}}\ .
$$
Let us show first by induction the double inequality
$$
x\le h_n(x)\le 2x\ , \qquad x\ge 3\ ,
$$
The left inequality is valid for all $x\ge -1$. For the right inequality we have in the case $n=1$ the inequality $x+\sqrt{x+1}\le 2x$, i.e. $x+1\le x^2$, which is true for $x\ge 2$, and inductively,
$$
h_{n+1}(x)=x+\sqrt{h_n(x+1)}\le x+\sqrt{2(x+1)}\le 2x\ ,\qquad x\ge 3\ .
$$
One can use this to show the existence of the limit
$$
h(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)
\ ,
$$
so $h$ is increasing, as a limit of increasing functions,
and we can use the two inequalities
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(x)&\ge x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+\sqrt{x+4+\sqrt{x+5}}}}}
\ ,
\\
h(x)&\le x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+\sqrt{x+4+\sqrt{2(x+5)}}}}}
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
to find a first location of the zero of $h$ between $-2$ and $-1$. On the RHS of the above inequalities we have monotone (increasing) functions, and the corresponding equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&= x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+\sqrt{x+4+\sqrt{x+5}}}}}
\ ,
\\
0&= x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+\sqrt{x+4+\sqrt{2(x+5)}}}}}
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
can be used to obtain lower and upper bounds for the zero of $h$ in the interval $(-2,-1)$.

---

The above equations are equivalent to
$$
\begin{aligned}
(((((x-0)^2-(x+1))^2-(x+2))^2-(x+3))^2-(x+4))^2&-(x+5)&&= 0
\ ,
\\
(((((x-0)^2-(x+1))^2-(x+2))^2-(x+3))^2-(x+4))^2&-2(x+5)&&= 0
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
My choice of weapons is now `sage`, and the real roots of the above polynomials 
which live in the interval $(-2,-1)$ are...

```
P = (((((x-0)^2-(x+1))^2-(x+2))^2-(x+3))^2-(x+4))^2-(x+5)
Q = (((((x-0)^2-(x+1))^2-(x+2))^2-(x+3))^2-(x+4))^2-2*(x+5)

roots_P = [ r for r in P.roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False)
            if -2 < r and r < -1 and r.imag() == 0 ]
roots_Q = [ r for r in Q.roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False)
            if -2 < r and r < -1 and r.imag() == 0 ]
```

This gives the exact placement of the roots:

```
sage: roots_P
[-1.208350985854702?, -1.180497738787836?, -1.115402635528049?]
sage: roots_Q
[-1.211810735228575?, -1.161954289026451?, -1.144052873349833?]
```

So far we have the lower bound `-1.211810735228575?` for the root of $h$
in $(-2, -1)$, coming from $Q$, but we do not have a "good decision" yet for the upper bound.
(Which is so far possibly `-1.115402635528049?`, but we are not in position to claim the upper bound `-1.208350985854702?`.)

A word about the shown sage decimals. The string representation for an element in $\bar{\Bbb Q}=$`QQbar` is exact, sage uses always an exact version of the algebraic element, determined by its minimal polynomial, and a "box" to localize the root in $\Bbb C$.

Let us analyze closer the situation. Let $a,b,c$ be the three roots shown for $P$ in the interval $(-2,-1)$. Then, a closer look shows that in fact we have introduced solutions by squaring, more exactly:

```
sage: a, b, c = roots_P
sage: a, b, c
(-1.208350985854702?, -1.180497738787836?, -1.115402635528049?)
sage: ( a + sqrt(a+1+ sqrt(a+2 + sqrt(a+3 + sqrt(a+4 + sqrt(a+5))))) ).n()
0.000000000000000
sage: ( b + sqrt(b+1+ sqrt(b+2 + sqrt(b+3 + sqrt(b+4 - sqrt(b+5))))) ).n()
1.08420217248550e-19
sage: ( b + sqrt(b+1+ sqrt(b+2 + sqrt(b+3 + sqrt(b+4 + sqrt(b+5))))) ).n()
0.0438259057173240
sage: ( c + sqrt(c+1+ sqrt(c+2 + sqrt(c+3 - sqrt(c+4 - sqrt(c+5))))) ).n()
1.08420217248550e-19
sage: ( c + sqrt(c+1+ sqrt(c+2 + sqrt(c+3 + sqrt(c+4 + sqrt(c+5))))) ).n()
0.145329668555162
```

so `b` respectively `c` is the root of the "cousin" of `P`, where the last, respectively the last two signs for the $\pm\sqrt{\ }$ expressions are taken to be minus.

The same can be done using next polynomials of degrees $2^6$, $2^7$, ... but the higher the degree, the more complex the computation and localization of the "good roots".

---

At this point, we have a proof of the location of the zero of $h$ in the interval between the numbers `-1.208350985854702?` and `-1.211810735228575?`, using a rather cheap estimation. The root of $h$ can be described in this fashion as a complicated limit of algebraic numbers, that do not have any structural connection. It is hard to say something more (in a structural way.) A numerical value was obtained in `pari/gp`.